# Escape characters in grep

Tags: regex, grep

I'm a little confused about how many backslashes are needed to escape the alternation operator `|` in regular expressions for grep. This

```bash
echo abcdef | grep -e"def|zzz"
```

outputs nothing, because grep is not in extended regex mode. Escaping with one backslash works,

```bash
echo abcdef | grep -e"def\|zzz"
```

prints `abcdef`. More surprisingly, escaping with 2 backslashes also works,

```bash
echo abcdef | grep -e"def\\|zzz"
```

prints `abcdef`. Escaping with three backslashes fails,

```bash
echo abcdef | grep -e"def\\\|zzz"
```

prints nothing.

Does anyone have an explanation, especially for the 2-backslash case ?

**Edit:**

Using this simple argument-printing program,

```c
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("Arg %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
}
```

I investigated what my shell does with the command lines above :

`-e"def|zzz"` becomes `-edef|zzz`

`-e"def\|zzz"` becomes `-edef\|zzz`

`-e"def\\|zzz"` becomes `-edef\\|zzz`

`-e"def\\\|zzz"` becomes `-edef\\\|zzz`

So all double-quotes are removed and the backslashes and pipes are not altered by the shell. I suspect grep itself does something special with the literal string `\\|`.

Comment: Is there a reason that you dont have space between -e and "def"?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou No reason. grep seems to accept both -e merged with the regex in one parameter, and -e separated as another parameter.

Comment: OK. It seems tha actually is something about grep that behavior is different in single quotes vs double quotes. Since it seems you are familiar with C (i am not that much) you can have a look in grep source : http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c

Comment: Sorry, but for bash it seems that there is a difference on double vs single quoting. Check this test and mind that args in double quotes are not parsed the same as args in single quotes in a bash function: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeGltTS1KTDdnWFk

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou In grep.c, I only saw `quote (input_filename ()));` which is probably not related to the regex. What makes you think grep searches for quotes ? Besides, my little program above shows the arguments the shell gives to grep, they have no quotes at all.

Comment: Yes, you have a point. I still believe that has to do with bash - see update in my answer.

Comment: if printf function of C has same behavior like in Bash, then should be a difference in double quotes - some slashes are lost . Can you compare with C printf if you see any difference in sending  `'\\\\|'` vs `"\\\\|"` ?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I'm on Windows, not bash. Single quotes have no special meaning there, with them instead of double quotes, the shell interprets the pipe as an inter-process pipe and doesn't even call grep.

Comment: Using Windows could be an important info... Let me understand something: does grep in single quotes vs grep with double quotes works different in your machine , like my tests?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou `echo abcdef | grep -e'def\|zzz'` yields :  'zzz'' is not recognized as an internal r external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hm  , oK . Sorry i can not help that much in Windows. In Linux, as you can see even on the online test link i sent you and on my answer, there is a difference between signle/double quotes. You might consider to change the subject of your question and your question to be clear that you talk about Windows and not linux grep. Also you could apply appropriate tags.

Comment: Use `echo abcdef | grep -E 'def\|zzz'`, as implied by **[the top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42823423/2430549)**.  I recommend you accept that answer, as this worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

The lowercase `-e` option is used to express multiple search operations.  The alternation is implied:

```
$ echo abcdef | grep -e 'def' -e'zzz'
abcdef
$ echo abczzz | grep -e 'def' -e'zzz'
abczzz
```

Alternatively, you can use the upper `-E` option for extended regular expression notation:

```
$ echo abcdef | grep -E 'def|zzz'
abcdef
```

I believe this solves you problem directly (either using `-e` for alternation or `-E` for extended regex notation).  Hope this helps :-)

FWIW, the issue with the backslashes is that `|` has special meaning to bash and needs to be escaped unless it is in single quotes.  Here is a resource on quoting and escaping rules and the common pitfalls:  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting

Comment: Please see my edit above, I don't think the shell alters my commands.

Comment: The shell's job is to do quoting and parse special characters (as described in the above link).  Also, my answer solves your original problem caused by using ``-e`` (which is for expression alternatives) instead of capitalized ``-E`` (which enables the extended regular expression notation).  The original problem is solved.  Everything else is just curiosity above bash quoting and escaping rules commingled with grep's quoting and escaping rules.

Answer (score 3):

If you double quote your regex, the shell [treats backslashes specially](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) (emphasis mine):

> The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or `newline`. Within double quotes, **backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed**.

This means that your expressions are treated as follows:

1. `grep -e"def|zzz"` – grep receives `def|zzz`; because it defaults to basic regular expressions (BRE), `|` isn't special<sup>1</sup> and grep tries to match the literal string `def|zzz`.
2. `grep -e"def\|zzz"` – `|` isn't one of the special characters mentioned above, so grep receives `def\|zzz`, and GNU grep treats `\|` as alternation<sup>1</sup>.
3. `grep -e"def\\|zzz"` – `\\` is special according to the manual excerpt (try `echo "\\"`); grep sees `def\|zzz` because the shell removes a backslash, and the behaviour is the same as for the second case.
4. `grep -e"def\\\|zzz"` – the shell turns this into `def\\|zzz` (`\\` becomes `\`, `\|` isn't special to the shell and stays unchanged); grep sees `\\` as a literal backslash ([backslash escaped by backslash](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Fundamental-Structure)), so `|` isn't special, and grep tries to match the exact string `def\|zzz`.

In general, it's prudent to single quote your regular expression so the shell leaves it alone.

As a side note, I don't think your C program is representative of how the shell processes arguments; in [Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation), [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) is a separate step and includes backslash processing (see [Escape Character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character)).

---

<sup>1</sup>As an extension, GNU grep allows you to escape `|` in BRE and get alternation. [POSIX BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) don't have alternation. As a consequence, the only difference between `grep` and `grep -E` for GNU grep is what has to be escaped; functionality is identical.

Answer (score 1):

The first fails because grep escapes the pipe programmatically, resulting in a *literal* pipe in the regex.

The last attempts fails because `\\\|` results in a *literal* backslash then a *literal* pipe in the regex.

```
echo 'def|zzz'   | grep -e "def|zzz"    --> def|zzz
echo 'def\\|zzz' | grep -e "def\\\|zzz" --> def\|zzz
```

Answer (score 0):

According to grep man pages, and especially according to info pages, all examples given for grep include single quotes and not double quotes.

Making some similar tests with single quotes we have a different and correct behavior:

```
$ cat file1
def
def\
def\\
def\\\
def\|
aaa
nnn
$ cat -n file1 |grep -e 'def|zzz'   #No results
$ cat -n file1 |grep -e 'def\|zzz'
     1  def
     2  def\
     3  def\\
     4  def\\\
     5  def\|
$ cat -n file1 |grep -e 'def\\|zzz'   #No results
$ cat -n file1 |grep -e 'def\\\|zzz'
     2  def\
     3  def\\
     4  def\\\
     5  def\|
$ cat -n file1 |grep -e 'def\\\\|zzz'   #No results
$ cat -n file1 |grep -e 'def\\\\\|zzz'
     3  def\\
     4  def\\\
```

**Conclusion : For regex in grep use single quotes.**

But to be honest, i don't know why the behavior is completelly different when using double quotes. Should have something to do with bash expansion.

**Update**

See this bash function test results that prove different interpretation of single vs double quotes in args:

```
function tt { printf "%s: %s\n" "$1" "$2"; }
tt -e 'def\\|aaa'  #Parsed correctly
tt -e 'def\\\|aaa'  #We send three slashes - function gets three slashes
tt -e 'def\\\\|aaa'  #We send four slashes - function gets four slashes
tt -e "def\\|aaa"  #We send two slashes but function displays ONE
tt -e "def\\\|aaa"  #We send three slashes but function displays TWO
tt -e "def\\\\|aaa"  #We send four slashes but function displays TWO


#Output
-e: def\\|aaa
-e: def\\\|aaa
-e: def\\\\|aaa
-e: def\|aaa
-e: def\\|aaa 
-e: def\\|aaa
```

Mind the case of three and four slashes inside double quotes.

One step more:

```bash
tt -e 'def\|aaa'  #Displays def\|aaa (correct parsing)
tt -e 'def\\|aaa'  #Displays def\\|aaa (correct parsing)

tt -e "def\|aaa"    #Displays def\|aaa (correct parsing)
tt -e "def\\|aaa"   #Displays def\|aaa (same as before - not correct parsing)
```

Probably the last two lines above in double quotes explain why the results in your test (`\|` vs `\\|`) have the same regex operation when enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: Please see my edit above, I don't think the shell alters my commands.