# Take information from a file with grep

Tags: linux, grep

I need to edit a huge file and only need to keep with the lines that start with `[INFO]`.

I already tried

```
grep "'[^INFO]*'"
```

and

```
grep-i '\[^INFO]*'
```

among other and none of them worked.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grep for strings with special characters like \[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18227567/608639), [grep for special characters in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12387685/608639), [Escape characters in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42822174/608639), [In a regular expression, which characters need escaping?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20804/56041), [escape character used in grep](https://askubuntu.com/q/851848), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `"'[^INFO]*'"` matches all lines with single quotes and no `I`, `N`, `F` or `O` characters see https://regex101.com/r/dDX5PQ/1 .
This is the case, because `[` and `]` are special characters and denote a rango of characters. When started with `^` it denotes a range of characters not to match.

The regex you want is `grep "^\[INFO\].*"`, which will match on all lines that start with `[INFO]` see https://regex101.com/r/bIEoBx/2 .